# Static public IP for NAT connection

Tags: networking, ip, nat, isp

I've Installed an Apache web server on my PC. I know an Apache server can be accessed by the public IP of my computer. But in my case, I do not have a unique public IP address. Because my ISP using NAT technology. How can I get a unique public IP?

- I've Requested to my ISP for static public IP for my connection they don't respond to my request!
- Is there any way to solve my problem or I've to request to my ISP again? (I've requested more than a time :( ...)
- Is it possible "can my ISP allot a special IP for me"?

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: A lot of ISPs just don't have enough IPv4 assesses to give you a public address. Almost all regions of the world are out of IPv4 addresses. IPv6 will be the solution once everybody finally adopts it. Until then you might very well be out of luck